# QTreeModel Not Displaying Required Data

Tags: pyside6

Why is my program not displaying the required data?
Please look into the program and identify why the data isn't displaying

---

```
`import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeView
from PySide6.QtCore import QAbstractItemModel, QModelIndex, Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel

class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.root = TreeItem(data)
        self._data = data
        indent = -1
        self.parents = [self.root]
        self.showData(data, indent)

    def showData(self, data, indent):
        indentations = [0]
        indent = -1
    
        if type(data) == dict:
            indent += 1
            position = 4 * indent
            for dict_keys, dict_values in data.items():
                if position > indentations[-1]:
                    if self.parents[-1].children_count() > 0:
                        self.parents.append(self.parents[-1].last_child())
                        indentations.append(position) 
                else: 
                    while position < indentations[-1] and len(self.parents)> 0:
                        self.parents.pop()
                        indentations.pop() 
                parent = self.parents[-1]
                col_count = self.root.column_count()
                parent.insert_children(parent.children_count(), 1, col_count)
                if type(dict_values) != dict:
                    child = parent.last_child()
                    child.set_data(1, str(dict_values))
                self.showData(dict_values, indent)
    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> int:
        if parent.isValid():
            return self._data[parent.row()].childrenCount()
        else:
            return len(self._data)
    
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> int:
        return 2
    
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
    
        item = self._data[index.column()] 
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item.data()
    
        return self.root.data(index.column()) 
        
    
    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if parent.isValid() and parent.column() != 0:
            return QModelIndex()
    
        item = parent.internalPointer()
        if not item:
            return QModelIndex()
         
        childM = item.child(row)
        if childM:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, childM)
        return QModelIndex()
    
    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        
        item = self._data[index.row()]
        if not item:
            return None
    
        parent = item.parent()
        if parent == self.root:
            return QModelIndex()
        else:
            return self.createIndex(parent.childrenCount(), 0, parent)
    
    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole) -> bool:
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
    
        item = self._data[index.row()]
        item.setData(value)
    
        return True
    
    def flags(self, index) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

class TreeItem(object):

    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        self.data = data
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []


    def set_data(self, column, value):
        if column < 0 or column >= len(self.data):
            return False
    
        self.data[column] = value
    
    def children_count(self):
        return len(self.children)
    
    def child(self, row):
        if row < 0 or row >= len(self.children):
            return None
        return self.children[row]
    
    def addChildren(self, children):
        self.children.extend(children)
    
    def data(self, column):
        return self.data[column]
    
    def last_child(self):
        return self.children[-1] if self.children else None
    
    def column_count(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def insert_children(self, position, count, columns):
        if position < 0 or position > len(self.children):
            return False
        for row in range (count):
            data = [None] * columns
            item = TreeItem(data, self)
            self.children.insert(position, item)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    data = {
            "root": {
                        "child1": "value1",
                        "child2": "value2",
            },
        }
    
    model = TreeModel(data)
    
    view = QTreeView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.expandAll()
    view.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I have been on this for quite sometime and tried adding more and more functions till I built it up to this stage.
I also used print method to print out data and it displayed the data, but the QTreeView displays only the column number.
what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Your code has many issues: the `indent` argument is completely useless, the row count and index references don't consider the parent level, `data()` returns arbitrary items based on the column even if you use the indexes of `_data` for the rows, you return the same data for **all** roles that are not `DisplayRole` (which is *wrong*). It seems like you're trying to adapt a 2d implementation to a 3d model, but that's obviously not possible without understanding how it works, and unfortunately your code has too many issues to give an answer that wouldn't require to rewrite almost all of it.

Comment: Thanks for your honest review. I still have a lot of learning to do.